# Multi-language blog using Jekyll

Tags: blogs, jekyll

I'm running my blog using Jekyll, and it is hosted on github.
My blogs are written in Chinese now, and I'm considering to write English version as well.

What is the best practice to support multi-language for the blogs so that readers can choose their preference language while reading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many plugins available for this scenario but unfortunately GitHub-hosted Jekyll blogs do not support any plugins since GitHub has disabled them for safety's sake. But if you choose to manually build and publish to GitHub, here are some pointers.

The following plugins are compatible with Jekyll 2.x:

- https://github.com/screeninteraction/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin103
- https://github.com/liaohuqiu/jekyll-multiple-languages97
- https://github.com/drallgood/jekyll-multilingual150

I liked neither of those since I found them too restrictive so I have created a plugin compatible with Jekyll 3.0 and very easy to use:

- https://github.com/vwochnik/jekyll-language-plugin

Of course, there are also approaches without any plugins, like the following:

- https://www.sylvaindurand.org/making-jekyll-multilingual/